# ASPNET MVC3: how to transform an anchor to Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following a href link:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/News/" +item.id+"/"+item.NewsSeoTitle)">title</a>
```

That i use for showing SEO-friendly urls; i would like, instead of the anchor tag, to use the `Html.ActionLink`.
How can i transform the anchor in `ActionLink` considering that i have not the Action name on the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Html.ActionLink` even when the `action` is not present in the URL; you just need an appropriate route. Routes are used for both inbound URL matching and outbound URL generation.

First things first, you'll need a route in the Routes collection to be used as a template for the URLs that you want to generate

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,                                          // name
    "News/{id}/{title}",                           // URL pattern
    new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }, // defaults
    new { id = "\d+", title = @"[\w\-]*" });       // constraints
```

This route will only match if `id` is a number and `title` contains only word characters and/or hyphens. The route needs to be registered before any more "general" routes as the order of routes is important; the framework stops on the first matching route, it does not try to find a "best" match.

Now you can use `Html.ActionLink` to generate routes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("title", "Index", "News", new { id = item.id, title = item.NewsSeoTitle })
```

You may also want to look at **[T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC)** ([available as a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/T4MVC)) too as it adds some overloads that removes the need for magic strings all over the place

Assuming your controller action looks like

```
public class NewsController
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

T4MVC adds an overload that allows you to use `Html.ActionLink` like

```
@Html.ActionLink("title", MVC.News.Index(item.id, item.NewsSeoTitle))
```

much neater :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom links which is not corresponding to the controller/action structure, maybe it's better to use your own html extension

```
public static string SeoLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string itemId, string title, string seoTitle)
{
    return String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",
        VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(String.Format("~/News/{0}/{1}", itemId, seoTitle)), 
        title);
}
```

As for `Html.ActionLink`: from the name of extension you can find the it work with actions. Of course you can provide such action and controller names to fit your requirements, but it's not a good idea, especially if your code will be supported by any other developer - he will never find such action in controller which is specified in `ActionLink` as `actionName` param.